# Getting started with massive data

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, nosql, large-data-volumes

I'm a mathematician and occasionally do some statistics/machine learning analysis consulting projects on the side. The data I have access to are usually on the smaller side, at most a couple hundred of megabytes (and almost always far less), but I want to learn more about handling and analyzing data on the gigabyte/terabyte scale. What do I need to know and what are some good resources to learn from?

1. Hadoop/MapReduce is one obvious start.
2. Is there a particular programming language I should pick up? (I primarily work now in Python, Ruby, R, and occasionally Java, but it seems like C and Clojure are often used for large-scale data analysis?)
3. I'm not really familiar with the whole NoSQL movement, except that it's associated with big data. What's a good place to learn about it, and is there a particular implementation (Cassandra, CouchDB, etc.) I should get familiar with?
4. Where can I learn about applying machine learning algorithms to huge amounts of data? My math background is mostly on the theory side, definitely not on the numerical or approximation side, and I'm guessing most of the standard ML algorithms don't really scale.
5. Any other suggestions on things to learn would be great!

Answer (score 2):

1. Apache Hadoop is indeed a good start, because it's free, has a large community and is easy to set up.
2. Hadoop is build in Java, so this can be the language of choice. But it is possible to use ohter languages with Hadoop as well ("pipes" and "streams"). I know, that Python is often used for example.
3. You can avoid having your data in data bases, if you like to. Originally, Hadoop works with data on the (distributed) file system. But as you already seem to know, there are distributed data bases for Hadoop available.
4. Did you ever had a look an [Mahout](http://mahout.apache.org/)? I think that would be a hit for you ;-) Many work you need, may already had been done!?
5. Read the [Quick Start and set up](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/quickstart.html) your own (pseudo-distributed?) cluster and run the [word-count example](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/mapred_tutorial.html#Example%3A+WordCount+v1.0).

Let me know, if you have any questions :-) A comment will remind me on this question.

Answer (score 0):

I've done some large scale machine learning (3-5GB datasets), so here are some insights:

First, there are logistics issues at large scales. Can you load all your data into memory? With Java and a 64 bit JVM you can access as much RAM as you have: for example, command line parameter `-Xmx8192M` will give you access to 8GB (if you have that much). Matlab, being a Java application, can also benefit from this and work with fairly large datasets.

More importantly, the algorithms that you run on your data. Chances are that standard implementations will expect all of the data in memory. You might have to implement a *working set* approach yourself, where you swap data in and out to the disk, and only work on a portion of data at a time. These are sometimes referred to as *chunking*, *batch* or even *incremental* algorithms, depending on the context.

You are right to suspect that a lot of algorithms do not practically scale, so you might have to go for an approximate solution. The good news is that for almost any algorithm you can find research papers that deal with approximation and/or discuss large scale solutions. The bad news is that you'll most likely have to implement those approaches yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop is great, but can be a pain in the ass to set up. This is by far the best article I've read on Hadoop setup. I strongly recommend it:
http://www.michael-noll.com/wiki/Running_Hadoop_On_Ubuntu_Linux_%28Single-Node_Cluster%29

Clojure is built on top of Java so it's unlikely that it's going to be any faster than Java. However, it is one of the few languages that does shared memory well, which may or may not be helpful. I'm not a math guy but it seems most math calculations are very parallelizable, with little need of threads sharing memory. Either way, you might want to check out [Incanter](http://incanter.org/), which is Clojure's statistical computing library, and [clojure-hadoop](http://github.com/stuartsierra/clojure-hadoop), which makes writing Hadoop jobs a lot less painful.

In terms of languages, I find that the differences in performance end up being constant factors. It's far better to just find a language you enjoy and focus on improving your algorithms. However, according to some shootout [cited by Peter Norvig](http://norvig.com/python-lisp.html) (scroll down to the colorful table, you may want to shy away from Python and Perl due to their crappiness with arrays.

In a nutshell, NoSQL is great for unstructured/arbitrarily structured data while SQL/RDBMS is great (or at least tolerable) for structured data. Changing/adding fields is expensive in RDBMS so if that's going to happen alot, you might want to shy away from them.

However, in your case, it seems like you're going to be batch processing a ton of data and then getting back an answer as opposed to having data around that you will periodically ask questions about? You could probably just process CSVs/text files in Hadoop. Unless you need a performant way of accessing arbitrary information about your data on the fly, I'm not sure either SQL or NoSQL would be useful.